# Warning on using std::remove_if on std::wstring (msvc c++20)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a function when takes a winapi HWND and returns wstring.

```
std::wstring utility::winapi::window_class(HWND hwnd) {
    int title_length = 20;
    std::wstring class_name;
    class_name.resize(title_length, '\0');
    GetClassName(hwnd, const_cast<LPWSTR>(class_name.c_str()), title_length);
    class_name.erase(std::remove_if(class_name.begin(), class_name.end(), [](const char &x){return x == '\0';}), class_name.end());
    return class_name;
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xmemory(2040): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
..\..\libs\utility\src\winapi.cpp(44): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::remove_if<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>,utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>>(_FwdIt,const _FwdIt,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _FwdIt=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>,
            _Elem=wchar_t,
            _Pr=utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xmemory(2040): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const char', possible loss of data
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xutility(5667): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from '_Elem' to 'const char', possible loss of data
        with
        [
            _Elem=wchar_t
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\xmemory(2036): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find_if<wchar_t*,_Fn>(_InIt,const _InIt,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _InIt=wchar_t *,
            _Fn=utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>,
            _Pr=utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>
        ]
..\..\libs\utility\src\winapi.cpp(44): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::remove_if<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>,utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>>(_FwdIt,const _FwdIt,_Pr)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _FwdIt=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>,
            _Elem=wchar_t,
            _Pr=utility::winapi::window_class::<lambda_1>
        ]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What is the meaning of this error?

UPD: updated with full error.

Comment: Is there any more compiler output? It indicates there is a warning, but the only thing in your question is a note. Notes generally accompany errors or warnings, they don't appear by themselves.

Comment: @cdhowie updated

Comment: `const_cast<LPWSTR>(class_name.c_str())` is generally a *really* bad idea. First and foremost, the size of the string won't be properly updated (a `std::string`/`std::wstring` can contain embedded zeroes, whish is the normal null-terminator). Use a plain array of `wchar_t` and then use it to initialize the `std::wstring` object.

Comment: Or perhaps that's why you use the erase/remove_if bit for? To change the end of the string? Well then you don't have to do that if you use an array, and then you can just `return` that array and a `std::wstring` object will be created with the proper length.

Comment: Note that starting with C++17, the pointer returned by the `data()` member function is _not_ a pointer-to-const. If you are using C++17, just replace `const_cast<LPWSTR>(class_name.c_str())` with `class_name.data()`. However, using a local array as a buffer as per the comment above would be better still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_name` is declared as a `std::wstring`. This is a string of `wchar_t` values, but your lambda argument is of type `const char &` which is more narrow.  The warning is telling you that the value might be truncated. This could cause the test `x == '\0'` to evaluate as true when it should note.  This is what the compiler is trying to tell you:

```
warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const char', possible loss of data
```

As a side note, there is no reason to take numeric arguments by reference.  In this case it will likely result in identical assembly since the lambda will almost certainly be inlined, but not using a reference is cleaner.

To fix the warning, change the lambda to accept a `wchar_t`:

```
[](wchar_t x){return x == '\0';})
```

Since C++14 you can also use `auto` as the type of a parameter:

```
[](auto x){return x == '\0';})
```

Comment: Thanks, both using wchar_t and changing const char& worked. Using wchar_t array looks better.